# I am trying to match two xml files and get the xml nodes from the first file as an output xml

Tags: c#, xml, compare, xslt-1.0, xmldocument

I am trying to write a c#.net application to match two XML's and get the nodes present in the first file that matches the second XML file.

The first XML contains more nodes than the template XML document. I am trying to match both of them and get the nodes which are present in the template XML from the source node. Below are the sample XML files.

XML Sample File 1

```
<document>
<node1>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node1>
<node2>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node2>
<node3>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node3>
<node4>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node4>
<node5>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node5>
```

XML reference file 2

```
<template>
<node2>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node2>
<node4>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node4>
```

Desired output is

```
<document>
<node2>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node2>
<node4>
    <subnode11>
        <subnode111 text="subnode">
        </subnode111>
        <subnode112 text="subnode">
        </subnode112>
    </subnode11>
</node4>
```

Below is what I have written in C#.

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlTemplateFilePathLocation))
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(xmlTemplateFilePathLocation, "*.xml");
            foreach (string xmlFile in filePaths)
            {
                uniqueFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlFile);
                string xmlContent = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile);
                if (!IsValidXmlString(xmlContent))
                {
                    xmlContent = RemoveInvalidXmlChars(xmlContent);
                }
                if (IsValidXmlString(xmlContent))
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(xmlFile, xmlContent);
                }

                string xsltTextString = string.Empty;

                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xmlns:ns=\"some:ns\">";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\" indent=\"yes\"/>";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<xsl:strip-space elements=\"*\"/>";

                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<ns:WhiteList>";

                Dictionary<string, List<int>> nodeTable = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile))
                {
                    while (!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        {
                            if (!nodeTable.ContainsKey(reader.LocalName))
                            {
                                nodeTable.Add(reader.LocalName, new List<int>(new int[] { reader.Depth }));
                            }
                            else if (!nodeTable[reader.LocalName].Contains(reader.Depth))
                            {
                                nodeTable[reader.LocalName].Add(reader.Depth);
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Read();
                    }
                }

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> kv in nodeTable)
                {
                    if (kv.Value.Count == 1 && kv.Value[0] == 1 )
                    {
                        xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<name>" + kv.Key + "</name>";
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < kv.Value.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < kv.Value.Count - 1)
                        {
                            //Console.Write("{0}, ", kv.Value[i]);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //Console.WriteLine(kv.Value[i]);
                            xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<name>" + kv.Value[i] + "</name>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "</ns:WhiteList>";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<xsl:template match = \"node()|@*\">";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<xsl:copy>";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<xsl:apply-templates select = \"node()|@*\"/>";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "</xsl:copy>";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "</xsl:template>";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "<xsl:template match=\"*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]\"/>";
                xsltTextString = xsltTextString + "</xsl:stylesheet>";

                //transforming the xml file with the generated XSLT

                StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
                TextWriter htmlWriter = new StringWriter(htmlOutput);

                File.WriteAllText(xmlTemplateFilePathLocation + uniqueFileName + ".xslt", xsltTextString);

                XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

                objXSLTransform.Load(xmlTemplateFilePathLocation + uniqueFileName + ".xslt", new XsltSettings { EnableDocumentFunction = true }, new XmlUrlResolver());

                string xmlFilexml = "C:\\Desktop\\Test\\XML\\722033_1004_2.XML";

                XmlReader readerXML = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilexml);

                objXSLTransform.Transform(readerXML, null, htmlWriter);
                htmlContent = htmlWriter.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine(htmlContent);
```

With the current code, I am only able to extract the main nodes and not the child nodes. I need to get the child nodes in the output as well.

If the parent nodes are matching I am considering them as a match. Node2 and Node4 are matched to the template XML and should come out in the output XML with their child nodes of the source XML.

I am using XSLT 1.0 and my final output will be in HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define a "match"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k if the parent nodes are matching I am considering them as a match. Node2 and Node4 are matched to the template XML and should come out in the output XML with their child nodes of the source XML.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't answer my question. How does one determine that the parent nodes are "matching"? The root element is named `document` in the 1st document and `template` in the 2nd; do they "match"?

Comment: we can ignore the root elements.